# output all data having the same id

Tags: php, jquery, sql, distinct

I have an update form with edit function on the side. for example a user created a form for warranty with three items with srfno4568. My code for displaying in a table works perfectly fine. My problem is how will I able to display the 3 items having the same id when a user wants to edit the data. I want all data regarding srfno4568 output in one.

here's my code for outputting one-by-one data:

```
$sql="Select sales.srfno, sales.datecreated, sales.clientid, sales.referenceno, sales.returnreason, sales.explanation, sales_item.srfno, sales_item.retqty, sales_item.retserial, sales_item.retdesc from sales INNER JOIN sales_item ON sales.srfno=sales_item.srfno ORDER BY sales.status='OPEN' AND sales.srfno='$ppid'";
            $res=$db->prepare($sql);
            $res->execute();    

            while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $srfno=$row['srfno'];
                $datecreated=$row['datecreated'];

                $tclientid=$row['clientid'];
                $retqty=$row['retqty'];
                $retserial=$row['retserial'];
                $retdesc=$row['retdesc'];
                    $cli="Select name, address, contactno, contactperson from client where clientid=$tclientid";
                    $client=$db->prepare($cli);
                    $client->execute(); 
                    while($clie= $client->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {
                        $clientname=$clie['name'];
                        $clientadd=$clie['address'];
                        $clientcontactname=$clie['contactperson'];
                        $clientcontact=$clie['contactno'];
                    }
                $referenceno=$row['referenceno'];
                $returnreason=$row['returnreason'];
                $explanation=$row['explanation'];

            }
```

and then I will just call them to output it

```
<td align="left">
<font color="#990000"></font>
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo $retqty ?>" />
<td width="8"><font color="#990000"></font><input type="text" name="serialno" id="serialno" value="<?php echo $retserial ?>"  />
<td><input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" value="<?php echo $retdesc ?>"/></td>
```

I can only output 1 item per edit form having the same srfno

Comment: HTML Basics: IDs must be unique!

Comment: Shouldn't be the `ORDER BY` part or your query be a `WHERE` statement?

Comment: @AminJafari but srfno are not the primary key. it is the foreign key between sales and item table